# Open jQuery UI Dialog from Code Behind

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am kind of new with jQuery and JavaScript, and I ran into a problem.

I am having some problems to open the jQuery UI Dialog Box from my ButtonField within the Gridview:

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="link" Text="Modify Deadline" Visible="true" runat="server" CommandName="modifyDeadline" ControlStyle-CssClass="button" ItemStyle-CssClass="sliderPopupOpener"/>
```

At first I tried to give a class to the above and named it sliderPopupOpener, and make it open the jQuery Popup when clicked as below:

```
$(".sliderPopupOpener").click(function () {
  $("#sliderPopup").dialog("open");
});
```

However, this was not working because of the postback, apart from that, it also does not work with my approach. Since I would like to get some data from the database before showing the jQuery UI Dialog. So I think the best approach is to call the Dialog function from the Code Behind.

How can I do this?

I tried this approach, but it did not work, I am not sure if I am doing something wrong.

```
if (e.CommandName == "modifyDeadline")
{
     string sliderPopupFunction = @" <script type=""text/javascript""> 
                                        $(function () { 
                                            jQuery(function () {
                                                $(""#sliderPopup"").dialog(""open""); 
                                            }
                                         });
                                    </script>";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "key", sliderPopupFunction);
}
```

Is the above possible? If so, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I noticed everyone is giving their answers with a way around this, rather than telling me whether this is possible just by calling the jQuery function from the Code Behind. Although I appreciate other solutions, I would appreciate if I could get this to work, with the least effort possible, through the code behind, since I have everything ready that way.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders thanks John, I was unaware of this. Thanks for the reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly bind the `click` event handler, you should try delegated events using [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (deprecated since jquery 1.7) or [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

That way, you should change this :

```
$(".sliderPopupOpener").click(function () {
    $("#sliderPopup").dialog("open");
});
```

Into something like this :

```
$(body).on("click", ".sliderPopupOpener", function(){
    $("#sliderPopup").dialog("open");
});
```

## alternative

If the code-behind approach is more suitable for you, you should try calling the method directly in your script, i.e, change this :

```
string sliderPopupFunction = @" <script type=""text/javascript""> 
                                    $(function () { 
                                        jQuery(function () {
                                            $(""#sliderPopup"").dialog(""open""); 
                                        }
                                     });
                                </script>";
```

into simply this :

```
string sliderPopupFunction = @" <script type=""text/javascript""> 
                                    $(""#sliderPopup"").dialog(""open""); 
                                </script>";
```

Also, if your `sliderPopup` is a server-side control, you should replace the `#sliderPopup` with the client Id generated by ASP .NET (using `sliderPopup.ClientID`).

Another thing to consider is if your `sliderPopup` located inside the update panel, you should try re-initialize the Jquery UI dialog first, something like this :

```
$("#sliderPopup").dialog().dialog("open");
```

Comment: Would this then be able to be called from the code behind, or is this change not related?

Comment: Using delegated events means your event handler should work across postback, so no need the code-behind. Also, I've updated my answer to include the proposed fix of the code-behind approach.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it all makes sense now :) Having said that, I still preferred the 'alternative' approach since I have everything in place that way, but it did not work. 

This is the code I have in the code behind:
string sliderPopupFunction = @" <script type=""text/javascript""> 
                                                    $(""#sliderPopup"").dialog(""open"");
                                                </script>";

                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "key", sliderPopupFunction);

Comment: Is your `sliderPopup` a server-side control? If yes, I've updated my answer to include that possibility.

Comment: Slider Popup is a div: <div id="sliderPopup" title="Modify Deadline"> it contains a jQuery UI Slider, some Labels and Two Butons.

Comment: it seems to have worked with the .dialog().dialog("open"); Let me try to bind data from the post back and confirm that's what I need :)

Answer (score 0):

I think in this situation it would be better for you to use a plain old `<input type="button/>` button and use ajax to perform your call to the server, and then with the returned data append it to your html and use the dialog. Ajax will perform your code behind without posting back your entire page.

EDIT: here is an example I did a while ago

```
//declaring the web method annotation allows this method to be accessed by ajax calls
//scriptmethod tells this method to take the data that we're returning, and encode it as a json so we can use it in javascript
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] 
        public static List<Person> getPeople() {
            List<Person> people = null;
            using (testDataEntities context = new testDataEntities()) {

                people = context.People.ToList();

            }
            return people;
        }
```

$(document).ready(function () {

```
        $("#getPeople").click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {},
                url: "Default.aspx/getPeople", //getPeople is the name of the method
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                  var data = msg.d;
                  var $table = $("<table></table>");
                   $.each(data,function(){
                    $table.append("<tr><td>"+this.MyProperty+"</td></tr>")
                    });
                  $table.dialog();
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

Comment: I believe I cannot insert a <input type="button"/> within the <asp:GridView> <Columns> field. Because I had tried that, since my functionality works perfectly outside the gridview.

Comment: @RyanSammut 

yes you can, you need to use the asp template though.

`<asp:TemplateField>
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <input type="button" />
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>`

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't know. I have managed to add it and it works as you said. Now the next challenge is to get the data how I want it through AJAX. What I want to know is how can I know which button in which row was pressed. From the code behind I usually use this: int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);. But if I do it through AJAX what do I need to do?

Comment: @RyanSammut
you could get the index of the row with jquery. give your plain input button a class.

<input type="button" value="submit" class="dostuff"/>
  $(".dostuff").click(function(){
    var index = $(this).closest("tr").index();
        alert(index);
    });

http://jsfiddle.net/maH2N/7/

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace the `<asp:ButtonField` with `<asp:TemplateField` the write whatever you want:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <input type="button" onclick='jsFunctionThatShowsTheDialog()'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```